# Apex - Generate HTML form through string

Tags: html, salesforce, apex

Can I create a HTML form through an apex String ? For instance, I want something like this.

```
     String example = "<p> This is my example </p> <br/>";
```

But what it returns is "

This is my example

", HTML tags does not have its real meaning in it. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

What if you replace the html elements with their html entity counterparts:

```
String example = "&lt;p&gt; This is my example &lt;/p&gt &lt;br/&gt";
```